# Laravel how to check is a paid member on all controllers

Tags: laravel-5

I have a paid members and general users. I need to check when users logins is paid membership expired or not. Currently I am checking when login redirects to profile page

```
    if(auth()->user()->type == 'paid' || auth()->user()->type == 'subscriber') {
        $user = PaymentController::checkPaid();
    }
```

How to check paid on logging in?

I tried adding the checkpaid into AuthenticatesUsers login method is it right way to do

```
    if ($this->attemptLogin($request)) {
        if(auth()->user()->type == 'paid' || auth()->user()->type == 'subscriber') {
            $user = PaymentController::checkPaid();
        }
        return $this->sendLoginResponse($request);
    }
```

Comment: What does the `PaymentController::checkPaid()` method do?

Comment: it checks paid membership expired or not when user logins